# What is the level of the log file?

Tags: python, web, logging, web-crawler, record

There is a task to write a `crawler` to crawl the webpage by python.
one of the requst is to specify the level of the log file, as is the level of detail of the log file. 
But I don't know what should be record? and what is the level of detail?
Can everyone give me an example?

Comment: "There is a task to write ..."  What is that?  what are you trying to do? do you have any code so far? Is this homework?

Comment: I posted a comment about Apache httpd log levels, but I'm not sure from your question whether you're parsing local log files or crawling external sites.  Can you provide that information?

Comment: @TokenMacGuy:Not a homework, Ths task is to write a crawler specified by the number of thread, the depth, the logfile, the level of the logfile, and I have inplemented most the the task, but I dont't know what should be recorded to distinguish different level of the log file

Comment: @K.G. That is what troubled me. He only says the level more higher, the log file should be more detaild

Comment: http://thejoyofcode.com/Logging_Levels_and_how_to_use_them.aspx

Comment: Then it sounds to me like it's up to you what it means to be more detailed.  Take a command line or configuration argument for log level, and choose which log entries are made for each log level.  Maybe you could use log levels like `error`, `warn`, `info`, `debug`, and provide more information at each of those levels? Ed: Curse you wim and your timely link.  Look at wim's link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is like what you're logging now:

```
12:01:08 Downloaded http://a.com/aaaaa/1.
12:02:51 Downloaded http://a.com/aaaaa/2.
```

This would be logging with more detail:

```
12:01:03 Preparing to download http://a.com/aaaaa/1...
12:01:03 Resolved host 'a.com' to '147.34.98.1'
12:01:04 Connected to 'a.com' (147.34.98.1)
12:01:04 Sent HTTP request http://a.com/aaaaa/1
12:01:06 Downloaded (48 KB in 1.5s) from http://a.com/aaaaa/1
12:01:08 Indexed http://a.com/aaaaa/1 (in 1.2s)
12:01:08 Downloaded http://a.com/aaaaa/1.

12:02:39 Preparing to download http://a.com/aaaaa/2
....
```

If you give control over log level, this might be a level in the middle:

```
12:01:06 Downloaded (48 KB in 1.5s) from http://a.com/aaaaa/1
12:01:08 Indexed http://a.com/aaaaa/1 (in 1.2s)

12:02:36 Downloaded (153 KB in 1.3s) from http://a.com/aaaaa/2
12:02:40 Indexed http://a.com/aaaaa/2 (in 1.6s)
```